# The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items

Tags: macos, permission

I am trying to delete files stored on a music system (NAD M50/52) on my network using a Mac (OS Sierra 10.12.6).  The music system HD is visible in Finder and, for the past 6 years or so that I've had it, I've been able to add or delete files (and edit metadata) using the Mac. That has recently stopped and when I try to delete some folders or files I get the 'Operation can't be completed.. permission...' message.  This only happens for some folders/files; others are editable and deletable.  When I use 'Get info' to view the folder properties, the Sharing Permissions part shows 'You have custom access' but there is no list of users, or no padlock shown.  I believe the music system HD is in Linux, but as I say I've been able to read/write to it in the past from the Mac, but not any longer now, at least not in every folder.  I've tried re-setting permissions using BATChmod but that did not work.  I'd be very grateful for any help/advice to fix this.

How can I understand / remove the permission error?

Comment: Since the Mac is just a filesharing client, it doesn't have control over permissions on the server (and generally can't even see them fully). You probably need to use the music system's management interface (via a web browser?) to see what's going on and fix it.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you so much Gordon for your prompt reply.  I had thought that, as there seems to be a lot of discussion about permissions problems on Mac forums, that somehow my Mac had changed the permissions on the music server and these had become stuck.  I'll investigate the server option.  Thank you again.

Comment: Have you got a Linux machine somewhere? Even Raspberry pi will do. It *might* prove easiest to take the drive out of its caddy and hook it up to a system that can handle the drive format natively. That should make you owner.